# TextView under ImageView with reduced text

Tags: android, textview, imageview

Can I this effect with text?

IMAGE
text

where the original text is : "image descriprion" and I would visualize "image desc...."

Is possible it?

Comment: You should consider opening Paint or something and trying to illustrate what you mean, then uploading that picture to your OP. It's difficult to visualize exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set [android:ellipsize="end"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) for a TextView then text longs text will be shortened with dots in the end.

"image descriprion" -> "image desc..."

Comment: i can't add image because is my first post. @aneal